# The most optimized way to find the sum of divisors of a number for numbers in a given range in python

Tags: python, math

I would like to find the sum of divisors of a number for numbers in a given range in the fastest possible way.

My current one looks like this

```
import math


def divSum(num):
    result = 0

    for i in range(2, int(math.sqrt(num)+1)):
        if num % i == 0:
            if i == (num / i):
                result = result + i
            else:
                result = result + (i + num / i)
    return int(result + 1)


list_of_number = [*range(0, 1000000, 1)]

print(list(map(divSum, list_of_number)))
```

At 100,000, the problems begin. Is there any way to optimize or the current one is fine overall. Thank you

Comment: I would take a look at [Chowla's function](https://oeis.org/A048050). The formula they provide is the [sum of all divisor](https://oeis.org/A000203) (which has a recursive formula) minus the number itself.

Comment: This answer might be helpful: [Is there a formula to calculate the sum of all proper divisors of a number?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/22723)

Comment: You might want to take a look to [`divmod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod) which gives you in one sentence the quotient and the remainder.

Comment: You could populate a look-up table from a file for the first million or so pre-computed values. I just coded the above algorithm in c and for numbers under 1 billion, it completed in under 2million cycles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your particular case I would say the fastest you can get is the Sieve of Eratosthenes.
This way we avoid work duplication.
Keep in mind that this approach is good as long as you need the result for all numbers between 0 and 1e6.
This might not be the best idea to compute the sum for a particular number.

```
# Set how many numbers we are testing
MAX = 1_000_000
# Initialize a list to avoid memory reallocation
# Set 1 as initial value as all numbers are divisible by 1
SUMS = [1] * (MAX + 1)
# Take every number and add it to all its multiples not grater than MAX
# No number not grater than MAX will have a divisor higher than MAX / 2
for i in range(2, (MAX + 1) // 2):
    # Don't start at i to avoid adding i to its own sum
    for index in range(i * 2, MAX + 1, i):
        # i is a divisor of index
        SUMS[index] += i
```

In my machine this code took 1.5 seconds.

Once we have the list `SUMS`, we can get the result of your function in constant time.
For all `i` from `0` to `MAX`, `SUMS[i]` returns the same as `divSum(i)`.